# Are computedFrom values observable inside a compose VM?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Inside my view I have the following

```
<compose
    view="./cars.html"
    view-model="../../view-models/cars"
    model.bind="{cars: $parent.$cars, activity: $parent.activity}">
</compose>
```

Then, the `cars` view model looks like this:

```
export class Cars {
    public data;

    public activate(data) {
        this.data = data.cars;
        this.activity = data.activity;
    }

    @computedFrom("data.allowedCars")
    public get maxAllowedCars(): number {
        return Math.floor(this.data.allowedCars / 2);
    }
}
```

And inside the `cars` view I have something basic like

```
<input
    type="number"
    name="allowedCars"
    value.bind="car.allowedCars"
    step="2"
    required />

<input
    type="number"
    name="maxAllowedCars"
    value.bind="car.maxAllowedCars"
    min="0"
    max.bind="maxAllowedCars" />
```

Now, the problem that I am having is that whenever I update `allowedCars`, my `public get maxAllowedCars()` doesn't get triggered as it should, hence the `maxAllowedCars` doesn't update.

This scenario works perfectly without `compose` (assuming all the code is in the same VM/view. However, I couldn't make it work using `compose`.

What I'd like is to find a way to trigger `maxAllowedCars()` every time the `allowedCars` field value changed...

Comment: Is this a typo here? Should be `model.bind="{cars: $parent.$car`. Not singular `car` (This is probably not the issue since `this.data.allowedCars` isn't throwing an error)

Comment: @adiga definitely a typo. It's `cars` and there's also a `repeat.for` inside the view I didn't cover in the example (didn't think it was necessary).

Comment: It's a bit confusing what your setup is like atm, can you help recreate it based on this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/j26kx06qny